# Matlab: Efficient way to sum tall array column values with upper limit

Tags: arrays, matlab

I want to create a new tall column with the following calculation.

batterycapacity(n) = batterycapacity(n-1) - consumed power + charging power.

batterycapacity and consumed power are both tall array columns. Charging power is a constant value.

**One side note is that the battery capacity can not be more then the maximum battery capacity.** (in this example 104kWh)
Could somebody give me a hand on how to set this up?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe try this docs article on custom tall array algorithms: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/develop-custom-tall-array-algorithms.html

Answer (score 1):

It would be something like:

```matlab
numNewMeasures = 1000;
numCurrMeasures = size(batterycapacity, 1); % Number of elements in the column array

batterycapacity(numCurrMeasures + numNewMeasures) = 0; % Extending the array
for idx = (numCurrMeasures + 1):(numCurrMeasures + numNewMeasures)
    batterycapacity(idx) = batterycapacity(idx - 1) - consumedPower + chargingPower;
    batterycapacity(idx) = min(batterycapacity(idx), 104e3); % Make sure value is below 104kWh
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. There is one important thing I forgot to mention. The variable "consumedPower" and "charging power" are both values of a tall column as well. When I modify the code to get it working, it takes a very long time to run through the for loop (4.6s / loop). Is there a way arround this? Thanks in advance.